# Convergence in measure, if $f_n \to f$ in measure then $f_n^2 \to f^2$ in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions converges to $f$ in measure. I need to prove that $f_n^2$ converges to $f^2$ in measure. But I got stuck here.

Comment: In general, this is true only if the measure is finite.

Comment: Thats correct, the measure space is finite.